# Efficient matrix-matrix product

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, vectorization, linear-regression

I'm trying to compute a matrix-matrix product inside a multilevel Bayes model. The data and model variables are shaped as follows:

```
X_train: (n_samples, n_predictors)
alpha: (n_groups, )
beta: (n_predictors, n_groups)
```

`X_train` is dense. The `alpha`s are the group intercepts and `beta`s denote the slopes (again, variable for each group). The samples are split in groups; the array `group_index` (of size `(n_samples,)`) indicates the group each sample belongs to. In a nutshell, the linear model is

```
y[n] = alpha[group_index[n]] + < X_train[n, 1:K], beta[1:K, group_index[n]] >
```

for all `n = 1 ... n_samples`, where the `< , >` denotes an inner product.

Here's how implemented this in Python:

```py
# an element-wise product between two matrices of size [n_samples, n_predictors]
y = alpha[group_index] + (X_train * beta[:, group_index].T).sum(axis=-1)
```

**Question**: Can this implementation be made more memory / cpu efficient?

Here `n_samples` can run up to 1 million, while `n_predictors` and `n_groups` are around 100 or so. What I'm looking for is a vectorized formulation that (1) requires lower storage and (2) runs about as fast compared to what I came up with above.

Comment: The comment says "an element-wise product between two matrices of size [n_samples, n_predictors]", but that doesn't seem to be what's going on in the code.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I think that _is_ what's going on: `X_samples` is `(n_samples, n_predictors)`, `beta` is  `(n_predictors, n_groups)` and `group_index` is `(n_samples,)`. Hence `beta[:, group_index].T` is of size `(n_samples, n_predictors)`.

Comment: Ah, `group_index` is an array.

Answer (score 0):

If you reshape `X_train` to `(N_samples,1,N_predictors)` and beta to `(1,N_predictors,N_groups)`, then you can compute a matrix multiplication between them that results in `(N_samples,1,1)`, which you can flatten before adding to `alpha[group_index]`.

```
X_train_r = np.expand_dims(X_train,1)
beta_r = np.expand_dims(beta,0)
y = alpha[group_index] + (X_train_r @ beta_r[:,:, group_index].T).ravel()
```

It should also compute nearly twice as fast.

Comment: It's not immediately clear to me how this solution is reducing my memory requirements. `beta_r[:,:, group_index].T` is of shape `(N_samples, 1, N_predictors)`

Comment: also, this solutions seems marginally faster (5% or so in %timeit tests)

Comment: Yeah it isn't quite reducing storage, as it still uses all of the values from X_train and beta. The efficiency gain is in the matrix multiplication; instead of multiplying two matrices of shape (1e6,100) and then taking the columnwise sum for 100 columns (each 1e6 values long), the matmul between (1e6,1,100) and (1e6,100,1) uses less multiply-accumulate operations. %timeit tests for 1e6 nsample and 100 for the rest gave 859 and 468 ms respectively.

Answer (score 0):

Another thing to try is:

```
alpha[group_index] + np.einsum('ij,ji->i', X_train_r, beta[:, group_index])
```

testing with a small example:

```
In [192]: A = np.arange(10)                                                              
In [193]: B = np.arange(50).reshape(5,10)                                                
In [194]: X = np.arange(50).reshape(10,5)                                                

In [195]: A + (X * B.T).sum(axis=-1)                                                     
Out[195]: array([ 300,  836, 1422, 2058, 2744, 3480, 4266, 5102, 5988, 6924])
In [196]: A + np.einsum('ij,ji->i',X,B)                                                  
Out[196]: array([ 300,  836, 1422, 2058, 2744, 3480, 4266, 5102, 5988, 6924])
```

and times:

```
In [197]: timeit A + (X * B.T).sum(axis=-1)                                              
14.1 µs ± 68 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
In [198]: timeit A + np.einsum('ij,ji->i',X,B)                                           
9.66 µs ± 9.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

and with Mercury's solution:

```
In [208]: A + (X[:,None,:]@B.T[:,:,None]).ravel()                                        
Out[208]: array([ 300,  836, 1422, 2058, 2744, 3480, 4266, 5102, 5988, 6924])
In [209]: timeit A + (X[:,None,:]@B.T[:,:,None]).ravel()                                 
7.3 µs ± 18.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

`matmul` is optimized for batch processing of matrix products, passing the arrays to fast math libraries (BLAS etc).